# How is there still iron on earth?

Tags: environmental-chemistry, iron

Iron rusts and the earth is pretty old, so how is it that there is still iron left that has not oxidized(/rusted)?

I tried looking it up, and the amount of iron on earth is mind boggling, but is that it?
Is there simply enough iron that not all of it has oxidized yet?

Maybe it's just that well insulated inside the crust, or does it occur naturally so more is created all the time?

Comment: There is very little metallic iron on the surface of the earth. And most of what is there is because humans *made* it by smelting iron-containing minerals, which are abundant.

Comment: The problem with availability of elements is often not the oxidation state but the concentration (or the dispersal). It would not be economical to collect all the rust falling off of vehicles to turn it into elemental iron. There is a similar issue with other elements, e.g. those used in electronics (although some of them do get recycled). There are some "[endangered elements](https://www.acs.org/greenchemistry/research-innovation/endangered-elements.html)" but iron is not one of them.

Comment: Although iron is ubiquitous ([Iron is the most abundant element, by mass, in the Earth, constituting about 80% of the inner and outer cores of Earth.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/cb300323q)), most of it is either molten or is complexed and not naked. So, there is little bare iron that can rust.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may confuse iron(1) as an element and iron(2) as the metallic form of iron(1). Rusting of iron(2) does not destroy iron(1), but converts it to iron(1) compounds like non-stoichiometric hydrated oxides.

Iron(1) of Earth is much older than Earth and the Solar system. But most of surface iron(2) is less than 100 years old. All but the one contained in rare meteorites was produced by men from iron(1) ores.

Iron(1) in [Earth's mantle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_mantle) and [Earth's crust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_crust) occurs in oxidized forms in various minerals, ores and rocks. E.g. the primary mineral of Earth upper mantle is [olivine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivine) $\ce{(Mg, Fe)2SiO4}$

There is also iron(2), together with nickel, in [Earth core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_structure_of_Earth#Core), at high temperature and extreme pressure, where is no rusting.

Comment: There was lots of elemental iron before the great oxygenation event that created all the iron oxide deposits we mine today. But that happened a bit over 100 years ago…

Comment: Sure, I have been implying that  It is usually being related to Snow ball Earth  era 2.5(?) bill. y. ago,  when CH4 GH effect  was being replaced by CO2 GH effect.

Comment: And majority even before that.

Comment: There can also be iron(1) formed from iron(2)-bearing minerals via [serpentization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpentinization). Essentially, the FeO displaced from mafic/ultramafic minerals by this process undergoes various redox reactions, including disproportionation to Fe3O4+Fe. Also Ni-Fe alloys are possible if nickel ions are in the minerals.

Answer (score 8):

You have it backwards. For about 2000 years people have taken iron oxides  (primarily) and converted them into metallic iron and steel. So there is dramatically more metallic iron on the earth surface now than 2000 years ago. about 6 million tons per day of new metallic iron/steel is made on earth each day. Admittedly much of that steel is recycled steel. Some mills only recycle metallic steel. Certainly many tons of oxides, etc, develop each day but I can't guess what that amount is except it is much less than new production of new metallic steel

Comment: I must admit very poor guess of tonnage by me . Wikipedia lists about 6 million tons per day . I have changed the answer but the error was so large I thought I should note it.